# How to log unhandled exceptions on sentry?

Tags: asp.net, sentry

i just initialized sentry on my asp.net 4.5 project but i only see logs that i manually added to my project.

i am looking for exceptions that i did not handle them or did not foresee them. is there any special mistake that i have done using sentry?

i just added this line of code in *Global.asax* :

```
  var ravenClient = new RavenClient("https://appcode");
```

i see no exceptions or warnings on my sentry project except event i sent to sentry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET, with `Global.asax.cs` you can override a method to handle errors:

```
        protected void Application_Error()
        {
            var exception = Server.GetLastError();
            ravenClient.CaptureException(exception);
        }
```